# How comes a Java-written software project ends up as an executable?

Tags: java, executable

I see that there are Open Source Java-written software that run from an executable. One example is [PDFsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/). It contradicts everything I learned about Java being a multi-platform, bytecode compiled programming language. I am confused. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually Java programs are run by calling the java bytecode interpreter e.g.

```
java -cp myprogram.jar
```

This works (at least in theory) on any platform that has support for the JDK.

But some programs (like Eclipse) add platform specific code, so that it looks nicer, runs more smoothly on Windows/Mac.

This is usually done by an .exe wrapper around the .jar file.

So to sum it up:

Programs that provide a .exe (or .app) file directly to execute are not 100% Java.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an installation .exe to me, not the project itself.  I just downloaded and ran it.  It installed the code to my system; it's all Java underneath.

Looks like the starter is a .exe too, but it's a Swing UI that uses Java:

```
PDF Split and Merge basic  
Version: 2.2.1 
Console version: 2.4.0e 
Developed by: Andrea Vacondio 
Build date: 31-Oct-2010 
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6 
Java version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.6.0_21-b07 
Max memory: 247Mb 
Configuration file: C:\Program Files\pdfsam\pdfsam-config.xml 
Website: http://www.pdfsam.org
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [gcj](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/)? That's one way to compile Java code into an executable. There are other ways too.

Comment: No! and I am happy to hear about it now. What famous project do you know of that used gcj?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this app is just an executable launcher than calls the java virutal machine with all the arguments necessary. Some software that you can look into for doing this are:

1. JSmooth
2. Jar2Exe
3. Launch4j

This website explains a lot about executable java files.
http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html

Answer (score 0):

The project you link to includes a batch file (windows) and shell script (*nix) that launches the JVM. If you look in the `bin` directory, you'll see them.

Answer (score -1):

There are certainly various ways to optimize Java programs by compiling them into executables.  Keep in mind though that this then means it's specific for that platform it's compiled for.

So as you rightly point out, the benefits of Java (write once, run anywhere) are lost.  But if you're looking to run a closed system where you control the hardware and server environments, it may be important for you to extract every ounce of performance.